# Using Bigquery for web analytics, how to filter out malicious bad data like bots etc

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using bigquery to analyze web traffic, and I have some problems figuring out how to filter out real users from bots and malicious request.

I can filter out based on IP, but it will quickly become a long query if I have to include all ip's that is bad. So that doesn't sounds like a good solution.

I can avoid it coming into BigQuery, but them problem is I only notice that it is bad/malicious/spam data after some time, I can't prevent it from getting it first. I can generate a query to find bots and take the result and feed it back to the ingest to block those from getting into bigquery, but that sounds like something other most have experience.

I can also ingest data in Bigquery, run my query to find malicious users and then create a new table with the cleaned up data. That could also be a solution, but I am missing experience of how others do it.

Is it just noise in your dataset that you must accept if it is a small percentage or what measures should I take?

Comment: Hi Kevin, this is a bit general question and I'm not sure tightly related to BigQuery as this is more of a security oriented issue. Maybe it will help focus if you can tell us what technology you use to build and host your Web site

Comment: This is more like a binary logistic regression, answering question like is this a spam Yes or No.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering by IP is a good idea. Only thing here is to keep bad IP address in a table so that your query would not grow when more IP is added.

```
SELECT * FROM my_visit_history
WHERE ip_addr NOT IN (SELECT ip FROM blacklisted_ips);

-- Or with a view to further simplify your future query:
CREATE VIEW my_clean_visit_history AS
SELECT * FROM my_visit_history
WHERE ip_addr NOT IN (SELECT ip FROM blacklisted_ips);
```